# Stop engaging in "eating disorder behaviors" or "eating disordered behaviors"?

Tags: compounds, modifiers, attributive-nouns

Which sentence is more grammatically correct?

> 1. We'd like you to refrain from engaging in **eating disorder behaviors** this week.
> 2. We'd like you to refrain from engaging in **eating disordered behaviors** this week.

A bit of context:

We consider an "eating disorder" to be an entity. We would say for example "this person has an eating disorder" or "this is an eating disorder behavior". An eating disorder behavior could be something like vomiting or over-exercising.

I am not referring to *disordered eating* here. For example, overexercising, use of laxatives, or use of drugs to control shape and weight and considered "eating disorder behaviours" and certainly are not "disordered eating". This is common nomenclature in my area.

What would be the grammatical justification for deciding on one of these sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a noun (including a compound noun) as an adjective (also known as a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)), you almost always use the "raw", unadorned noun:  It's a "shoe store", not a "shoes store", for example.  So, when talking about a behavior that is caused by a certain disorder, you would refer to a "disorder behavior".

Since you have a compound noun as your adjective, The [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf) recommends that you hyphenate it:

> gerund + noun:
>   *running shoes
>
>   cooking class
>
>   running-shoe store*
>   Noun form open; adjective form hyphenated.
>   <sub>*--from page 3 of the linked table*</sub>

So, the recommended form is actually ***eating-disorder behavior***.

Answer (score 0):

*Eating disorder behavior* (singular) is technically correct, but very vague. The phrasing I hear most often for the group of behaviors associated with (or that might lead to an eating disorder) is *disordered eating*. For maximum clarity, just name the specific thing you want to address like binge eating or excessive calorie counting.

I work in a college health center where we provide eating disorder education, awareness, and treatment. Here are two credible resources that might be useful: [How to talk to someone about an eating disorder](http://www.nationaleatingdisorders.org/what-should-i-say), 
[mindful eating program description](https://cmhc.utexas.edu/mindfuleating.html)

Comment: 'eating disorder behavior' is  just fine. It's not the same as 'an eating disorder'. Just because you binge once doesn't mean you have an eating disorder, but binging is a behavior associated with eating disorders and repeated binging is considered a sign of an eating disorder.

Comment: I think Brandy's answer added something to the conversation and I didn't think she was attacking the other answer.  She provided a good reference for the OP along with some help.

Comment: I disagree with this. I am not referring to disordered eating here. For example, overexercising, use of laxatives, or use of drugs to control shape and weight and considered "eating disorder behaviours" and certainly are not "disordered eating". This is common nomenclature in my area.